# Raspberry Pi 4 19.10 Firefox DRM not available

Tags: 19.10, raspberrypi, drm

Trying to upgrade my early Pi 4/4gb from Raspian to Ubuntu.

Installed 19.10 64 bit.  Wildvine is not installed with the default installation and there is no option in Firefox to turn on DRM.  There were some workarounds for Chromium on Raspian.

Is there a way to enable DRM on the Pi 4 Firefox?
Where can I get a copy of Wildvine to install?
Are there other options to stream DRM protected content?

Comment: Might best ask Mozilla that question.

Comment: If you just started having DRM problems today or yesterday, I did too. However, no DRM problems on my chromebook that shows no widevine installed. I think (but I'm not positive) this might have to do with a feature that is available for chromebooks and windows that is not available for linux and that is to allow "Protected content identifiers". This option does not exist for us on regular linux, only Windows and Chromebooks.

Comment: Also, it depends on who is providing the DRM content. From what I understand, Disney Plus does support Ubuntu but Charter Spectrum does not.

Comment: Streaming is UK BBC, Channel 4, and Channel 5.  Channel 5 broke last week on Raspian but the others are good.  I was hoping that the  newer Firefox on Ubuntu would include DRM handling.  It doesn't seem to have the option.